# fonts and images and not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, fonts

I have deploy my application on AWS with nginx and passenger .My images, fonts and icons are not loading .I have look for the possible solution on internet like   config.assets.compile = true and did RAILS_ENV = 'production' rake assets:precompile but nothing working for me

Comment: Have you restarted the server after pre-compiling the assets?

Comment: yes i have restart my server but didn't  work